# Create a table with every possible input in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, testing

I am new to SQL and having a hard time figuring out how to implement what I am trying to do. Currently my testers manually create a file with every possible input to put through our programs. What I want to do is create a stored proc that takes in some input tables and sets up every possible input for them. Currently I have two tables. The first is TestFileColumnHeaders with two columns, ColumnID and ColumnName with the format

> ColumnID    ColumnName
>     _ _ _ _     _ _ _ _ _
>     1         Foo
>     2         Bar
>     3         Baz

This table is for the headers on the input file that is being created. Then I have a table for the possible inputs called TestFileColumnInfo with columns ColumnID and ColumnInfo with the format

> ```
>  ColumnID  ColumnInfo  
>  _ _ _ _   _ _ _ _ _  
>  1         Foo1  
>  1         Foo2  
>  2         Bar1  
>  2         Bar2  
>  3         Baz1
> ```

The output I want for my proc is a table like

> Foo      Bar       Baz
>     _ _      _ _       _ _
>     Foo1     Bar1      Baz1
>     Foo1     Bar2      Baz1
>     Foo2     Bar1      Baz1
>     Foo2     Bar2      Baz1

I tried a Cartesian join but I dont want to have Foo1 and Foo2 to show up in the same row on the output so thats where I am stuck. Only for an unlimitied number of headers and inputs. Is there a way to do this in T-SQL? Do I need to change the design of my tables to something else? Also Sorry If the editing is off. I cant figure out how to keep the correct spacing for my headers and underlineing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this (simple version):

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnInfo AS foo
    FROM TestFileColumnHeaders  h
    INNER JOIN dbo.TestFileColumnInfo i ON h.ColumnID = i.ColumnID
    WHERE ColumnName = 'Foo') foo
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnInfo AS bar
    FROM TestFileColumnHeaders  h
    INNER JOIN dbo.TestFileColumnInfo i ON h.ColumnID = i.ColumnID
    WHERE ColumnName = 'Bar') bar
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT ColumnInfo AS baz
    FROM TestFileColumnHeaders  h
    INNER JOIN dbo.TestFileColumnInfo i ON h.ColumnID = i.ColumnID
    WHERE ColumnName = 'Baz') baz;
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd1d2/4)**

If your number of columns are not fixed, you will have to do a dynamic sql.

Comment: You are amazing and I regret that I lack the reputation to upvote you. Thank you for helping me expand my knowledge of SQL